# How can I split a string into 5 variables?

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

How can I split the following string into 5 variables?

(Bedrijfsnaam:variable1) (Contactpersoon (achternaam):variable2) (E-mail adres:variable3) (OS:variable4) (OS User:variable5) [ID:416129849993661001953:ID]

I always get this string and I need the variables like this:

```
$var1 = "variable1";
$var2 = "variable2";
$var3 = "variable3";
$var4 = "variable4";
$var5 = "variable5";
```

The rest of the string is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex, this should get you started:

```
$sString = '(Bedrijfsnaam:variable1) (Contactpersoon (achternaam):variable2) (E-mail adres:variable3) (OS:variable4) (OS User:variable5) [ID:416129849993661001953:ID]';

if(preg_match_all('#:([^\)]+)#', $sString, $aMatches)) {
    var_dump($aMatches[1]);
}
```

**Edit:**
You asked me how to capture empty variables. Let me explain what is happening in the regex a little.

The `#`'s are delimiters to tell where the regex starts and stops, let's ignore those.

The colon right after the first delimiter (`:`) matches the colons in the string where you want your "capture" to start.

Then the interesting part `[^\)]+`, this matches everything up to the first parenthesis `)` it encounters. The brackets `[]` ( a "character class" ) followed by the `^` basically means match everything BUT what is followed by the `^`, in our case a `)`. The `+` tells the regex to match **1** or more.

So all we have to do to match **0** or more is to use the astericks `*` which does exactly that.

```
$sString = '(Bedrijfsnaam:) (Contactpersoon (achternaam):variable2) (E-mail adres:) (OS:variable4) (OS User:variable5) [ID:416129849993661001953:ID]';

if(preg_match_all('#:([^\)]*)#', $sString, $aMatches)) {
    var_dump($aMatches[1]);
}
```

---

I'm normally not the "hand a guy a fish type". So if you have any questions pertaining what is happening here, let me know.

Comment: All of the variables can also be empty for example (Bedrijfsnaam:). I need to save that also as an empty variable. Is that possible with a regex?

Comment: I improved my answer to accommodate your request.

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for explaining it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```
<?php

$pattern = ':([a-z0-9\s]*)';
$subject = '(Bedrijfsnaam:variable1) (Contactpersoon (achternaam):variable2) (E-mail adres:variable3) (OS:variable4) (OS User:variable5) [ID:416129849993661001953:ID]';

preg_match_all(
  $pattern,
  $subject, 
  $matches
);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

I edited the pattern so that spaces are also recognized.

Comment: There are no spaces between the string.